# Spring Session Repository List All

Tags: spring, session, spring-security, spring-session

I need in my project more session management than I thought at the beginning. The major feature that I need is to list all sessions for (or per) identified principal (for example to delete/invalidate all his session id's). I don't want to use `SessionsRegistry` because of distributed kind of a system.

So two questions:

1. How to list session ids in Spring-Session (Do I need to come with custom implementation) ?
2. Is there a way to set sessions time-out that is not interval between requests but max session time life?

Typical use case for such functionality is to prevent malicious user to continue his activity by blocking his account and invalidate his all sessions across the servers.

Comment: I think for now the only way is to query database/repository... which is not good solution I think

Comment: @Tomek I agree, we resolve this by using own user session management.